# How can you remove (or hide) the caption bar in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, filter, jqgrid, caption

I see you can add a top caption bar and put a title by using this code:

```
jQuery('#grid').setCaption("Title");
```

Is there anyway, if I have already set a title, to remove the caption bar?

I tried this but it just removes the text (doesn't remove the whole caption bar).

```
jQuery('#grid').setCaption("");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you want hurry, 
test

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").hide();
```

or if you have multiple grids, then only hide titlebar of $("#grid"), then do

```
$("#gview_grid > .ui-jqgrid-titlebar").hide()
```

Answer (score 7):

If you create jqGrid having no title bar (`caption: ""`) and examine the grid with respect of Developer Tools or with respect of Firebug you will see the `<div>` with the class "ui-jqgrid-titlebar" having `<span>` with the class "ui-jqgrid-title" and the anchor with the class "ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close" as the child elements:

```
<div id="gbox_list" class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    ...
    <div id="gview_list" class="ui-jqgrid-view">
        <div style="display: none;"
             class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top ui-helper-clearfix">
            <a style="right: 0px;" class="ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close HeaderButton"
               role="link" href="javascript:void(0)">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-n"></span>
            </a>
            <span class="ui-jqgrid-title"></span>
        </div>
        ...
```

So even you create the grid without the title bar jqGrid **create all hidden elements of the title bar**.

I looked through the jqGrid code where the caption are created and could find the following fragment

```
if(ts.p.caption) {
    ...
    $(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close",grid.cDiv).click( function(e){
    ...
} else {$(grid.cDiv).hide();}
```

So to have the same results as with the grid initialized with `caption: ""` parameter you can do following

```
var mygrid = jQuery('#list'),
    cDiv = mygrid[0].grid.cDiv;
mygrid.setCaption("");
$("a.ui-jqgrid-titlebar-close",cDiv).unbind();
$(cDiv).hide();
```

You should do unbinding from the minimize button only if you are sure, that the grid will not have the title (`caption`) later. The bindings took less resources and do nothing for the hidden grid.

So [the suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284141/how-can-you-remove-or-hide-the-caption-bar-in-jqgrid/5284297#5284297) of Pravat Maskey just to hide the title is absolutely correct and my investigations only confirm this.